# php preg_match replace result duplicate

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I am a newbie in preg_match patterns, so I would be glad if someone could help me for next situation:

I need to replace those string:

```
[popup="about"]about me[/popup]
```

to

```
<a href="#PopupAbout"  data-plugin-options='{"type":"inline", preloader: false}'>about me</a>
```

I have tried with `$pattern = '/\[popup="(.*?)"\](.*?)\[\/popup\]/';` but it does not give me expected result, it give duplicated results. And how can I replace it all in a simple way!

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\[popup="about"\](.+?)\[/popup\]'~, 
   "<a href=\"#PopupAbout\" data-plugin-options='{\"type\":\"inline\", preloader: false}'>$1</a>",
   $str);
```

Comment: That looks like interesting, I will try this later at home

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/\[popup="(.*)"\](.*?)\[\/popup\]/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

I get this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [popup="about"]about me[/popup]
    [1] => about
    [2] => about me
)
```

You can test it online here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: You should use a reluctant quantifier `.*?` instead of `.*`. See [when it fails](http://regex101.com/r/zF7mL4)